# Programatically importing a file and creating an instance of a class in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have a (python) list of strings which refer to python source files and subsequently classes within those files which I want to import and then create an instance of the classes within the files (everything follows a strict naming convention, making this theoretically possible), in Ruby I would do something like:

```
require "lib/sources/#{source}.rb"
s = source.constantize.new
```

How would I do something similar in Python?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [Dynamic Module Loading in Python](http://technogeek.org/python-module.html):

> If you have a need to import a module
>   in python and, for whatever reason,
>   you will not know the name of the
>   module until run-time, python provides
>   the built-in `__import__` function.